# enable download on html from my asp page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, cross-domain

I want to be able to download the html contents of my page from a client after receiving a post request (XMLHttpRequest and doing some processing. Is there a setting I must enable for this to be possible? I've tried enabling COORS via

```
           Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

with no success. Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Update: I am using ASP.NET Web Forms (with NET 4.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think the CORS stuff is for cross origin scripting - to enable JavaScript calls to a domain different than the original request.  As far as getting the HTML contents, I believe you mean to get the response of the web server as it is posted back to the client.  Not knowing what technology you have used (i.e., MVC, ASPX, etc.) you may want to look into interceptors.  They differ depending on the technology.  For ASPX, check out....

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30907/The-Two-Interceptors-HttpModule-and-HttpHandlers

Comment: turns out that I had an exception firing which was the reason it was not working. The above does work for enabling cross origin scripting.